# GPUImage work with other OpenGL Context failed

Tags: ios, opengl-es, eaglcontext

In my projiect , I get a opaque filter framework which based on `GPUImage`. 
I wanna create an app can have a video call just like FaceTime,so I use this filter framework provided OpenGL `ViewA` to render camera image,Using my own openGL `viewB` to render remote video stream.
now I get a problem  .**the `viewA` was irregularly show the `viewB`'s content.**
 **particularly when the viewA's frame changed.** like this:
[image]
the remote Video pixel format is I420 and the local video pixel format is NV12. so technically the `viewA` must can't render `viewB` 's content. Like you can see:the `viewA` show the gray image of `viewB`. I assume `viewA` get the the Y planar data of `viewB` somehow. when viewA show gray image,it's frame rate slow down greatly.
because the `viewA` belong to a opaque framework,I can only control own OpenGL rendering part `viewB`.I don't know how to resolve this bug. It most likely the two EAGLContext is conflict,or `viewA` and `viewB` shared the render/texture buffer somehow?
Anyone,please help me.I am struggling this several days.

Answer (score 0):

It's turn out that the OpenGL context confused management lead to this problem.